# Event study using Panel data or Fixed effects

Tags: regression, categorical-data, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I am looking to analyse the impact (causal effect) of a conflict on firm valuation (using daily prices) for a sample of around 800 firms (I currently have this data over a sample period of around 365 days).

I want to analyse the overall impact but also identify the difference in impact between the industries (maybe some industries got affected to lesser/more extent).

However, i cannot decide on the most appropriate methodology to use. I am split between using an event study methodology or panel data methodology using fixed effects.

Both seem to have their pros and cons but I am not sure panel fixed effects is appropriate, given the short time frame (only a few days around the start of the war).

Any help is appreciated!

I have tried to look for posts with similar questions but have not found anything specific to my question.

Comment: Have you investigated our [posts about time series intervention analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=time+series+intervention)? That would seem to be what you are asking.

Comment: @whuber I am unfortunately not familiar with that methodology yet. Is that methodology also applicable for panel data?

Comment: "Daily prices" says to me you have time series data, which makes this a standard intervention analysis.  How do your data differ from that conception of the problem?

Comment: @whuber I understand it that time series data in combination with cross sectional data is considered panel data, no? Kind regards.